# Nativescript vue, how to get the .apk file?

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

By following nativescript docs, installed all dependencies and `tns doctor` dont find any error.

and followed a tutorial and ran the following commands,

```
npm install -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-init
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template hello-vue
cd hello-vue
npm install
```

All sets fine and then i did my coding for an simple app then i ran below command:

```
npm run watch:android
```

This deploy the app in my connected android phone.

so my question is how can i get the apk file, so that i can send to another person?

Note: sidekick even not opening my folder. and when running `tns build android` shows `No project found at or above 'C:\wamp64\www\newapp' and neither was a --path specified`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For building the apk for android, use the following command:**

```
tns build android --release --key-store-path <path-to-your-keystore> --key-store-password <your-key-store-password> --key-store-alias <your-alias-name> --key-store-alias-password <your-alias-password>
```

Lots more info here : https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps

**If you want to get the debug apk using `tns debug android --bundle`,  it will be located here :**

```
<your project folder>/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

**If you are having trouble running `tns`, install nativescript globally using:**

```
npm i -g nativescript
```

And follow the simple prompts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for (it sounds like you want a `debug.apk` instead of an `output.apk`), but you might want to look at the documentation for [publishing an Android app](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps).

Comment: `tns build android`, i tried that, it says "No project found at or above 'C:\wamp64\www\native-vue-app' and neither was a --path specified."